# RJ45 female to male fault

Tags: networking, wiring, rj45

i have the following - common - problem, on one end of the cable, there are RJ45 **males** *T586 **A*** which are connected to a 8-port switcher, on the other end, there supposed to be RJ45 **females** _T586 **A** which in turn will allow another RJ45 male to be connected.

the commonly used color scheme was followed on males

(having the head down)

- blue white
- blue
- orange white
- green
- green white
- orange
- brown white
- brown

the problem i believe is located on *female* end of cable, which i try multiple time to follow the numbers designated by the module, which is the list above in reverse, and as listed resulting in no signal transmission. tried the T586B (both ends) for device to device once, but no results.

Which is the proper way of handling this wiring?

There were also additional RJ45 females with the numbers 6-5-4-3, but 1 to 8 isn't supposed to be used for this?

Comment: Why are you doing it this way?

Comment: the wiring males->females was already in place when i first got there, so i assume the owner, didn't want any cables lying around or something like that, even the cat5e cables where build inside the walls..

Comment: where's *orange*? Also, the standard's name is TIA/EIA 568 and the wiring / colour schemes [***are different from what you're describing***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIA/EIA-568#Wiring) since the blue/blue-white pair is always at pins 4-5, no matter the cabling variant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you're using rj45 females. No, I'm not being mysoginistic here, but you really should use cables of appropriate length instead of cobbling things together. Throw out these cables and buy new ones at correct length with rj45 males at both ends.

Comment: i understand why the hate on rj45, i too couldn't get anywhere near on even blinking the light on testing tool.
But i still hoped that there was a way and  i just can't seem to find, we "temporary" switched females to males and everything was working ..

Comment: @GeoPhoenix Electrons don't care about male or female plugs, all they do care about is conductivity, impedance and electro-magnetic fields. You can get a working installation with male/female cables, it just would not be standards-compliant

Answer (score 6):

A network cable should always be a RJ45 plug (male) on both ends.  If for some reason you really can't replace the cable with the correct length, use a [RJ45 coupler](http://www.startech.com/Cables/Network/Network-Adapters/Cat5e-RJ45-Modular-Inline-Coupler~CAT5COUPLER) rated for network use.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you need to do here:
1. You definately need to change your cables, it seems whoever put them there in the first place might not have known what they were doing.
2. if you are using 'T568A' or 'T568B' you need to make sure that whichever color scheme you use, it is followed throughout your network i.e. from workstation to switch. if you are not making your cables yourself then you should really go with the most common color scheme, this will save you a lot of stress.
3. get a cable tester, it could also be the case that wear and tear may have damaged your cables.

Comment: #1 is so true!!